# how to get all the translated words from google translation through C#?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, google-translate, google-translator-toolkit

In my windows application, i have to translate some word from 'English' to 'Hindi' language.I have using GoogleTranslation.cs for accessing and getting translated content from google. This is a small code snippts.

```
// Initialize the translator
using RavSoft.GoogleTranslator;
Translator t = new GoogleTranslator();
t.SourceLanguage = "English";
t.TargetLanguage = "Hindi";
t.SourceText = "bus";

// Translate the text
t.Translate();
Console.WriteLine (t.Translation);
```

It retrieving the translated word successfully.But i also want to **get some more suggessted words offered by google translation page**.for example if you want to translate a word **Bus** to Hindi languages then google translated like **बस**.Also, if you want to know alternative translated words then we have to click the translated word.Now,It's showing list of suggested translated words in a popup.So, I want to retrieve this list of words also.Kindly refer my attached picture for better understanding.

[image]

Is this possible to retrieve all those alternative translated words? Guide me to get out of this problem...

Comment: What is "GoogleTranslator.cs"? A link whould be helpful

Comment: Actually, GoogleTranslator.cs file can be used to send the web request to google translation page with carrying request data along with the url.finaly catch the web response(html content) and parse the html content for getting the translated text.

Comment: any final solution with full source code sample working about it ?

Comment: @Kiquenet : No...Google currently stopped the service.That option only available in payment mode...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that `GoogleTranslator.cs` is some kind of wrapper around google api... you are out of luck. According to [this FAQ](https://developers.google.com/translate/v2/faq?hl=ru) (the bottom statement) this functionality is not availible via google translate api calls.